# draw amplitude_time chart of audio using Highcharts in android

Tags: javascript, android, audio, highcharts

I want to develop an application in which we can get the voice of a person and draw a it's amplitude-time chart. my teacher told me to use Highcharts to draw the chart. but I can't understand how to pass audio amplitude to javascript function to draw. I searched for this. One way was sending parameters in URL but I can have the amplitude information of voice in a array of double numbers that it's length will be very big number for example for a audio recorder with fs=8000 which record 8000 sample in a second, so if I have 5 second long it's array length will be 5*8000.I'm not sure I can send array of double with this such length, is it possible? Is there any other way I can use? I can send hole data to the java script and draw chart or divide it in a special size and send it frequently and complete the chart real time if it is possible in Highcharts.

consider the following code, and also consider every time byteData [] read data from file it want to draw it's information on on the chart, I mean I should send this array to highcharts (Java script function) to draw it.(skip code that is related to the AudioTrack which I used to play audio)

```
 private void PlayAudioFileViaAudioTrack(String filePath) throws IOException
     {
     if (filePath==null)
     return;

     int intSize = android.media.AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(RATE,                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
     AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT); 

     AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
     AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, intSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM); 


     if (at==null){ 
     Log.d("TCAudio", "audio track is not initialised ");
     return; 
     }

     int count = 512 * 1024; // 512 kb
     //Reading the file..
     byte[] byteData = null; 
     File file = null; 
     file = new File(filePath);

     byteData = new byte[(int)count];
     FileInputStream in = null;
     try {
     in = new FileInputStream( file );

     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
     }

     int bytesread = 0, ret = 0;
     int size = (int) file.length();
     at.play();
     while (bytesread < size) { ret = in.read( byteData,0, count); if (ret != -1) { // Write the byte array to the track 
         at.write(byteData,0, ret); bytesread += ret; } else break; } 
in.close(); at.stop(); at.release(); }
```

Comment: How your data looks like, which is returned by "any audio receiver". Its a array or something different?

Comment: Yes It is Array of double

Comment: Could you be more specific, we need any code or example of your array. Is is possible to use JSON to communicate between front/back-end ?

Comment: Honestly Im not familiar with this kind of solutions, and you need to consider how you can communicaate your two layers. I advice you to check how to inject your response to javascript (generally) or use a json.